# Ag-Grid Grouped Cell Click Does Not Provide CellRendererParams

Tags: angular, ag-grid, ag-grid-angular

I have a column which groups multiple fields using the `autoGroupColumnDef` for the actual grouping.  For the first grouping I have also defined a custom `cellRndererFramework` component and included `cellRendererParams` for that component in the column definition.  The component includes a clickable icon and is displaying as expected.

When clicking the icon from the renderer the `cellClicked` event is firing with the `CellClickedEvent`, but the event shows that the cell renderer used is the default `agGroupCellRenderer`, not my custom one.  As such, I only have access to the group renderer params, not the custom ones I provided in the column definition.

**Is there a way to retrieve cell renderer params from a custom renderer on cell clicked when used as a part of the default column grouping?**

The column definition used for the column in question is:

```js
 {
   field: 'name',
   sort: 'asc',
   rowGroup: true,
   hide: true,
   cellRendererParams: { canDelete: true, deleteField: 'id' },   // Used in cellClicked handler
   cellRendererFramework: DeleteGroupRendererComponent
 }
```

**Edit:** Below is the DeleteGroupRendererComponent code.

```js
import { ChangeDetectionStrategy, Component } from '@angular/core';

import { ICellRendererAngularComp } from 'ag-grid-angular';
import { ICellRendererParams } from 'ag-grid-community';

@Component({
  templateUrl: './delete-group-renderer.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./delete-group-renderer.component.scss'],
  changeDetection: ChangeDetectionStrategy.OnPush
})
export class DeleteGroupRendererComponent implements ICellRendererAngularComp {
  params: ICellRendererParams;

  rowId: string | number;

  constructor() {}

  agInit(params: ICellRendererParams): void {
    this.params = params;
    this.rowId = params.value;
  }

  refresh(): boolean {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please share your `DeleteGroupRendererComponent` and post the example on stackblitz if possible.

Comment: @DurgeshPal - Added the custom renderer component code, though I don't know that it will be terribly relevant.  Will work on adding a demo when I can!